# How large were the Deathstar plans, in GB?

Tags: star-wars, technology, death-star, rogue-one

In Rogue One we know that the Deathstar plans...

> ...reside on a single harddrive, and it took a long time to transmit the data via the antenna at the Scarif base.

Can we determine approximately how large the Deathstar plans are (in Earth units like GB, TB)?

Comment: I don't see how there's any way to answer this. We don't know the giant-communications-tower-to-Rebel-ship transfer rate. Not to mention the fact that the data isn't even stored on a hard drive, it's a "data tape". And "data tapes" (plural) if you remember Admiral Motti's comments in ANH. We have no idea about the capacity or transfer speed and therefore know nothing about size.

Comment: Things like "one hard drive" and "took a long time to transmit" don't tell us much about the "size" of the plans. Data transfer rates trend at roughly the same rates as disk capacity. We also don't know how the plans are stored. Are these holograms? Are they vector models? Do they include wiring? Are sub-structures included? There really is no good way to know what kind of content to expect. The best assumption would be that the Death Star plans were likely 100 to 1000 times as "large" as "typical plans".

Comment: ...don't forget the freehand red circle saying *"Shoot Here"*

Comment: This is answerable (at least in part).

Comment: @Valorum - agreed. Say it was autocad, and a large building with volume of 1,000,000 cubic metres needed 100Mb file. And say you could fit 1,728,000,000 such buildings into the death star.  Then you'd need about 17.28 petabytes for the file.  These are rough calculations.  It depends how detailed the plans were.

Comment: @Tim - For all we know, the plans are a cut/paste job that only takes up a few MB and they've left it to the construction teams to fill in the blanks. That's why it's only barely operational after that many years of building it.

Comment: @Valorum - what, you mean like the plans consist of a 120km-diameter sphere, and that's all?  And maybe an arrow pointing to a spot with a sign saying "mega death weapon goes hear" in crayon?

Comment: @tim - The plans for St Paul's Cathedral ran to around 2-3000 drawings of various complexity. Using today's technology you could render those (or even scan them) in a few tens of megabytes; https://www.stpauls.co.uk/history-collections/the-collections/architectural-archive/wren-office-drawings

Comment: @Valorum - right, and I said 100Mb. Not sure what the volume of St Pauls is, but remember that the Death Star is 120km in diameter, hence my figures.

Comment: But more importantly - was it a zipped file?

Comment: One other issue is it fits inside R2 in something which is hardly bigger than a random usb drive. So why do they need to store it in what looks like a 5.5" hard drive if it fits in something almost 1/100th of the volume?

Comment: Construction plans also avoid redundancy by having one set of drawings that cover many identical floors or sections. You don't have to literally have a separate plan for every square inch of a building.

Comment: Ah, the Death Star plans are just a bunch of black and white gif files. That's exactly what they look like in the original movie.

Comment: @TheIronCheek I'm in content production. We haven't produced tapes of any kind in over a decade, yet I still field calls from customers wanting to order the "tapes". Jargon often hangs around long after it is useful and eventually even changes meaning. In this case, "tape" means "a data medium".

Comment: @meneldal Archive houses often operate on last decade's tech.

Answer (score 10):

We can't speak to Earth-equivalent measurements, but we do know that the hard disk in question had a maximum capacity of **512 million *exanodes*** ([whatever the hell those are](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6946/what-is-a-quad)).

The disk apparently included not only the plans for the Death Star but also the complete design history and a log of all communications regarding the project.

[image]

<sub><sup>[Star Wars Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Rogue-Ultimate-Visual-x/dp/146545263X)</sup></sub>

Comment: It was too big to be sent as an email attachment.

Comment: Very cool! I guess the follow-on question is: What's the conversion of _exanode_ to Earth units? Is this unit used anywhere else in the canon universe where it might give a clue?

Comment: @Luke - The only mention of exanodes (outside this book) seems to be from the Rogue One prequel, again in relation to the information vault.

Comment: So, 512 yottanodes, whatever nodes are.

Comment: This is very misleading. If a node is a binary element you'd still have 512x10^24 bits =  6.4x10^25 bytes. The "monomolecular switching binary" *thing* seems to indicate that each molecule of the tape is a binary element, and if there is 100 grams of usable tape (between buffers) and the assuming the tape is some kind of silicate, you'd only get like 3.56x6x10^23 bits or 2.67x10^23 bytes... So... even using every molecule of a 100 gram silicate tape you still don't get anywhere near anything resembling 512 million exa-"bits" (which must be smaller or equal to a "node").

Comment: Frankly, unless the tape is 10kg or more there's no way even "monomolecular binary switching" tape is holding 64 yottabytes.

Comment: @GorechestopherH - A node might be equivalent to a terabyte or a byte. We just don't know. Neither is beyond the realms of reality though.

Comment: @Valorum Take a look at my comment. It is beyond the realm of reality. With 1 molecule per bit, still beyond reality.

Comment: @Gorchestopher - Perhaps they've got better materials tech than we have? Or better compression.

Comment: @Valorum Compression should never factor into the storage statistics of a data drive. If that was the case why not just say "it has a capacity of 9e99 GB, as long as you're storing a 9e99 GB bitmap that is composed entirely of 0's... that has been zipped to 1 physical KB, *then* stored to the drive. Even with the best possible materials tech "mononuclear switching binary" suggests 1 BInary elemenT per molecule, which is already insane, but still falls far short of the 6.4e25. In fact, in order for the figure to be conceivable the drive would need to be able to store 100 bits per molecule.

Comment: A "node" is probably a sector. Or 2KiB (4KiB for Flash memory).

Comment: @Gorchestopher is correct. This drive is impossible. Not that "physically impossible" *ever* stopped the creators of Star Wars.

Comment: ok, so we know the *capacity* of the cartridge, but not what percentage was actually utilized to store all the information.  Presumably it wasn't terribly close to being filled...

Comment: @GorchestopherH - I don't know where you've got this idea that one exanode is equal to trillions of bytes. Maybe it's a thousand bytes. Or a hundred. Heck, my thumb drive has 33 million k on it. Maybe an exanode is a k

Comment: @Valorum "Exa" is a metric prefix meaning 10^18. So it wasn't an idea I had to get very creative with.